# How can i check the truth of a sub-verb-obj triple?

Tags: nlp, sparql, dbpedia, knowledge-graph

what am i trying to do is trying to build a system that takes for entry a subject, verb, object triple and check whether it's true or not.

for example:

`{Elizabeth , is , queen} => true`

`{Obama, won, nobel prize} => false`

What i have tried:

i tried to make some `ASK` queries but i've never succeeded since i am new in SPARQL and DBpedia.

i don't know what prefix to choose or what property

for example how can i decide if `obama` is of type `dbo:Person` and so on ...

every query is different and i am lost :(

Note: it does not have to be perfect or to work with any kind of information
thank you

Comment: why are you doing this? Yet another question answering or fact checking system? There are plenty of those. And obviously, you have to find a way from your text to the URIs in DBpedia. This is non-trivial. Like "won" you would map to which property in DBpedia? And "Elizabeth", how do you map it to the "correct" DBpedia resource URI? This is research topic

Comment: you could have a look into related work in literature. maybe you'll get an idea of how it could work and about the difficulties in this area

Comment: It's important to also note that the fact that some triple(s) exist(s) (or don't) in some database is not necessarily an indication of "truth" (or "untruth"). Vandals regularly put untruths into Wikipedia, which may get digested into DBpedia, and I'm sure similar things happen with Wikidata. Much research effort lies before you...